# How to set UIButton's Highlight Tint color programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

There is a `Highlight Tint` option in Interface Builder for `UIButton`. Is it possible to change it programmatically for all `UIButton` in iOS 5....using some kind of appearance protocol thing or some other workaround?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set it as

```
[button setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

This is equivalent to hightlight tint option in IB and is applied only for highlighted state.

**Update:**
In order to implement this for all the buttons in app, use this:

```
[[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

It will set for all the `UIButton` which you are going to use in your app.

Check this for more details on [UIAppearance protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: can't i do it generally for all buttons? eg doing something like '[UIButton setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]'

Comment: i did it like this -----      
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) 
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [(UIButton *)view setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        }
    }

but this requires a view reference....

Comment: Use this, [[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]; It will set for all the UIButton which you are going to use in your app. Dont do it using for loop. Updated my answer as well.

Comment: the appearance thing for setting tintColor for UIButton doesnot work :(

Comment: I am not sure why that happens then, ideally it is supposed to work and I have used it with searchbar, navigation bar and toolbar. I am not sure if that is a bug with apple or it is not supported for UIButton then. In that case you might have to manually set this for each and every button using the first line. Since that is a subquestion, probably you can raise this as a new question.

Comment: @ACB I don't think the highlight colour and the tint colour are the same thing.

Comment: According the official doc regarding property `tintColor`: "This property has no default effect for buttons with type UIButtonTypeCustom. For custom buttons, you must implement any behavior related to tintColor yourself."